# Remove a class instance from a list

Tags: python, object

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if anyone has any workarounds, that would be great.

If have a class like so:

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

And I add a bunch of instances of this class to a list, like so:

```
people = [person("Bob"), person("Tim"), person("Sue")]
```

I would, in a perfect world like to then perform this code:

```
people.remove(person("Bob"))
```

However, unfortunately, due to the way classes work, this is not possible. Is there some sort of workaround for this? Preferably something that fits onto one line?

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Know that you can also define something like `def __eq__(self, other): return self.name == other.name` Then your code will work as written.

Comment: @Inazuma,  are you creating the instances in the list or appending already created instances to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious/intuitive way might be:

```
people = [person for person in people if person.name != 'Bob']
```

Comment: Yes, that is obvious, should have realized that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the names are unique:

```
people = [person("Bob"), person("Tim"), person("Sue")]


people[:] = [ins for ins in people if ins.name != "Bob"]
print(people)
```

Comment: @PascalvKooten, the answers are actually not the same, you reassign the name, my code updates the original object/list.

Comment: That only makes a difference if more references to the object are in play, correct?